# delete from file except for a specific type: kubectl delete -{not}l type=volume -f file.yml

Tags: kubernetes

With command:

```
$ kubectl delete -l type=volume -f file.yml
```

K8s will delete all object with label `type=volume`;

I need some command to do the opposite, something like:

```
$ kubectl delete -{NOT}l type=volume -f file.yml
```

This command should delete any object in a file except for object with labels `type=volume`, it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `NOT` operator `!` in the `=` check with `key=value` pair as:

```
kubectl get pods -n dummy -l role=x    # lists all pods with label role=x
kubectl get pods -n dummy -l role!=x   # lists all pods with label role!=x
```